# making multiple sub-directories

Tags: command-line

How would you make 2 sub-directories under data file.

```
F:.
├───DATA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you are asking, so I'll give two examples:

```
md foo foo\bar 

md foo foo\bar foo\baz
```

..you get the idea.

Comment: `md foo\bar foo\baz` is enough on a default configuration of Windows. No need to explicitly create the intermediate directory levels.